# How to share a subscription with family members in android using the family library?

Tags: android, google-play

We have followed these [steps](https://www.howtogeek.com/337810/how-to-set-up-google-family-to-share-your-google-services/) for sharing the subscription to the family members. But it was not working. We need to share the subscription via family sharing (family library) for family members and children (under 13).

In this [document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852?hl=en) mentioned "You can't share in-app purchases and free apps with your family members".
Is it possible to share the subscription with the family members?

If any other way is available to implement an android subscription with family members (family library), Let us know, Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found a solution?